# Automatically add photos shared with me to Google Photos

Tags: automation, google-photos

I use Google Photos for all photos I take.  When we have an event, friends and I tend to share photos to each other, using Google+. I can see the photos fine - but I really want a way of making them part of my own photos library.

Ideally, I'd like to just say "automatically absorb any photos or albums shared to me" - but failing that, I can't even find a manual way, besides what I'm doing at the moment, which is individually downloading every single photo and then re-uploading it into Google Photos.

Is there a way I can automate this?

Comment: Certainly you can save a step by having the [Google Photos Desktop Uploader](https://photos.google.com/apps) running on your computer. It'll automatically upload photos you add to your hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very familiar with Google+, but what you could try is to sync the folder on your mobile device where every shared picture of the Google+ App is located on your phone (works only with Android devices). This is how I can do this with shared WhatsApp pictures. As I said, I'm not sure if there is such a folder for this app.